# Reloading page on every click using Polymer and app-route

Tags: polymer

I am using app-route and iron-pages with a paper-toolbar to display my views.

On one of my views, `main-view`, displays a randomly chosen image which changes each time the page is loaded. Every time `main-view` is selected from the toolbar, the page should reload so that a new image will be shown.

The problem is, if I am already at the `/main-view` url and I select it from the toolbar it doesn't refresh the page. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing "hard reloads" per se as `app-route` is designed around a [SPA-concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Instead you should *observe* your `selectedView` prop and trigger a new image fetch if the `selectedView === "main-view"` .  Furtermore you can add an `on-tap` on your main-view button in the toolbar and refetch when tapped && `selectedView === "main-view"` so it reloads even on the same page - Can you share a fiddle/JS-bin with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should definitely add `on-tap` to render new images. Your image won't change, because `iron-pages` are observing some value (specified in `selected` property) so, when you click on main-view and route property already had value "main-view", observer will not trigger.

Adding on-tap on element that is handling changes will make it always trigger. 
Some easy example:

```
<iron-pages selected="{{route}}" attr-for-selected="name">
  <example-element name="main-view" on-tap="handleClick" id="main"></example-element>
  <another-element name="second-view"></another-element> 
</iron-pages>
```

and inside `handleClick` function something like:

```
handleClick: function() {
  this.$.main.renderImage();
}
```

Of course inside `main-view` element you can declare `renderImage` function which will handle rest of the logic

And don't forget to make some debounce since you don't want to propably render 20 new images in 1 second. You can use Polymer native `debounce` function
You can read more about it here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods